# android expandablelistview, expand the view only on click of group indicator, open new activity if clicked any where but groupindicator

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListView on my Activity, where group contains image and name, while child contains variant of group (name, id etc). Regardless I click on the expand/collapse button, or on the any where in group, it expands/collapses always. What I want, the list to expand/collapse only if user clicks on the indicator. How can I do this? For clicking on the TextView, I want to open the different activity. Unfortunately OnGroupClickListener does not provide this info.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Tell me if i have get your question correctly, you want two action on clicking on group that is when clicked on text it should open a new activity and when clicked on indicator it should expand/collapse rite???

Comment: @Clairvoyant, You got it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that by doing some modification in your **custom Adapter** `getGroupView` method  and adding two more method in your **custom Adapter** which will be called depending on the view clicked. Here I am posting an example code:

```
    //Add these two methods in your Custom Adapter 
    public void OnIndicatorClick(boolean isExpanded, int position){

     }

    public void OnTextClick(){

    }   

    //this is the getGroupView code
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }



        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        lblListHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(_context, "text Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_list_group_indicator);
        indicator.setSelected(isExpanded);
        indicator.setTag(groupPosition);

        indicator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(_context, "Indicator Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                OnIndicatorClick(isExpanded,position);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

And now from the **Activity** you can call the **Custom Adapter** like as below code which will override those two methods which we have added in **Custom Adapter**

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    listDataHeader, childDataList){
       @Override
       public void OnIndicatorClick(boolean isExpanded, int position) {
          if(isExpanded){
             expandableListView.collapseGroup(position);
          }else{
             expandableListView.expandGroup(position);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void OnTextClick() {
          //Do whatever you want to do on text click
      }
 };

 expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set `setOnGroupClickListener()` to your ExpandableListView and return true, Like :

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
    return true;
}
```

this will disable click of group and then set onclicklistener() on which you want to expand group.